Cluster bootstrap for standard errors using fixest
I am trying to estimate a model with fixed effects using feols from the fixest package. As I only have few clusters, I would like to obtain bootstrapped clustered SEs. Does anyone know a package that might do this or should I implement it myself?
I switched from plm to fixest because I have daily data (pdata.frame with indexes 'Athlete' and 'Date') but want year fixed effects, and plm always computed daily fixed effects.
There is the package fwildbootstrap, but it doesn't return standard errors, and vcovBS doesn't work with the model estimated using feols.
Code used:
t <- feols(TotalN ~ factor(Conditions) + i(Sex, Age) + i(Sex, I(Age^2)) + 
        factor(Month) + Total.Climb + excl:after_excl | Athlete + Season,
      data = simple_excl)

vcovBS(t, cluster=~Athlete)

# Error in model.frame.default: variable lengths differ


Check out my recent answer on this.

Note that with few clusters (<42) the wild bootstrap might be more suitable, that it only provides p-values is by design.

Is it possible to recalculate SEs using the wild bootstrap?
